# ESP32 Socket client not connecting to python server

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking, esp32, micropython

**Hey!**
Am a developer trying to establish a socket connection between my pc and an esp32 connected on the same network.

### Code

On esp32(micropython)

```py
import usocket
import network

def do_connect():
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    if not wlan.isconnected():
        print('connecting to network...')
        wlan.connect('whydoesnt', 'itwork')
        while not wlan.isconnected():
            pass
    print('network config:', wlan.ifconfig())

def connect_socket():
    addr = ("192.168.1.4", 80)
    s = usocket.socket(usocket.AF_INET, usocket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(addr)

    s.send("hello")
    s.close()


do_connect()
connect_socket()
```

On my computer (python3.9)

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 80))
s.listen(3)

while True:

    client, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected by {}".format(addr))

    while True:
        content = client.recv(32)

        if len(content) == 0:
            break

        else:
            print(content)

    print("Closing connection")
    client.close()
```

Am hosting the socket server on `0.0.0.0` so that it runs on the wifi network.
Well, the python server works. I tested it using puTTy running on the same pc. I just had to get my ip address from cmd and connect to it using putty.

### Error

But, when I tried doing the same with the esp32, it didn't work, and gave me this error:

```sh
network config: ('192.168.1.10', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 24, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 19, in connect_socket
OSError: [Errno 113] ECONNABORTED
```

**Well, thank you in advance!**

Comment: Your computer likely has a firewall which blocks incoming connections from the network. Have you taken this into account?

Comment: Well, thanks! I later checked another stackoverflow question which solved the issue. I had to allow python.exe and secure socket tunneling protocol access through my firewall.

Comment: @redicrafty consider adding that as an answer and then (after the waiting period) accepting it.  That way this question will no longer show up as 'unanswered'.